# My unique function is not working on array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, set, unique

I have a function designed to sort / order / uniqify a given array.

Here is some of the code:
Bubble Sort -

```
function sort(postsCollection, type, direction){
    let target = postsCollection[0][type];
    let swapp = false,
        n = postsCollection[0].length - 1,
        x = postsCollection[0];
    do {
        swapp = false;
        for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(x[i][type] < x[i+1][type]){
                x[i+1] = x[i];
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
        n--;
    } while (swapp);
    return x;
}
```

These exist in module.exports:

```
    orderPostsCollection(postsCollection, sortType, direction, callback){
    // Unique Array Creater
    let uniq = a => [...new Set(a)];

    if(!sortType && !direction){
        callback([...new Set(postsCollection)]);
    }

    if(sortType) {
        callback(sort([...new Set(postsCollection)], sortType, direction));
    }else if(direction){
        callback(sort([...new Set(postsCollection)], false, direction));
    }
},
uniqify(postsCollection, callback){
    console.log([...new Set(postsCollection)]);
    callback([...new Set(postsCollection)]);
}
```

it should make the data array unique. But it isn't..

Here is a sample:

```
{"posts":[{"author":"Rylee Paul","authorId":9,"id":1,"likes":960,"popularity":0.13,"reads":50361,"tags":["tech","health"]},{"author":"Zackery Turner","authorId":12,"id":2,"likes":469,"popularity":0.68,"reads":90406,"tags":["startups","tech","history"]},{"author":"Zackery Turner","authorId":12,"id":2,"likes":469,"popularity":0.68,"reads":90406,"tags":["startups","tech","history"]},{"author":"Zackery Turner","authorId":12,"id":2,"likes":469,"popularity":0.68,"reads":90406,"tags":["startups","tech","history"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Elisha Friedman","authorId":8,"id":13,"likes":230,"popularity":0.31,"reads":64058,"tags":["design","tech"]},{"author":"Adalyn Blevins","authorId":11,"id":37,"likes":107,"popularity":0.55,"reads":35946,"tags":["tech","health","history"]},{"author":"Adalyn Blevins","authorId":11,"id":37,"likes":107,"popularity":0.55,"reads":35946,"tags":["tech","health","history"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Jon Abbott","authorId":4,"id":46,"likes":89,"popularity":0.96,"reads":79298,"tags":["culture","tech"]},{"author":"Bryson Bowers","authorId":6,"id":85,"likes":25,"popularity":0.18,"reads":16861,"tags":["tech"]},{"author":"Bryson Bowers","authorId":6,"id":85,"likes":25,"popularity":0.18,"reads":16861,"tags":["tech"]},{"author":"Bryson Bowers","authorId":6,"id":85,"likes":25,"popularity":0.18,"reads":16861,"tags":["tech"]},{"author":"Bryson Bowers","authorId":6,"id":85,"likes":25,"popularity":0.18,"reads":16861,"tags":["tech"]},{"author":"Bryson Bowers","authorId":6,"id":85,"likes":25,"popularity":0.18,"reads":16861,"tags":["tech"]}]}
```

why is this array is not made unique? what gives the above result?

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming `[...new Set(data)]` will filter out duplicate values – which is basically correct – *but*: `Set`s only filter out duplicates of [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) (strings, numbers, booleans, etc.). Objects are not considered equal to each other even if they have the exact same content<sup>✝</sup>.

You could instead call your own `uniqueFilter(postsCollection)` function instead of using `[...new Set(postsCollection)]` that does filter objects based on the sameness of their content (see [here for some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)).

---

<sup>✝</sup> Objects are only considered "equal" to each other when they're literally references to the same object. e.g.

```
const a = {};
a === {}; // false

const b = a;
a === b; // true (because `b` is literally pointing to the exact same object as `a`)
```

Think of every object you make as having a secret key that always makes it unique regardless of its content.

Comment: I recently discovered that `[...new Set(arr)]` does not remove objects since they are seen as Object:object